# If statement does't change background image

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

The if statement gives me the correct information for `swipeDirection` and `swipeLength` and I've obtained both the results of the IF and the ELSE except for the image changing.

```
if ( (swipeDirection = 'down') && (swipeLength >= 180) ) {
     touchEnabledElement.style.backgroundimage = 'railroadtracks.png';
     document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "IF" + 'Start H:' + startX + ' V:' + startY + '<br>' +  ' End H:' + curX + ' V:' + curY  + '<br>' + "Swipe Length: " + swipeLength + '<br>' + 'Swipe Angle: ' + swipeAngle + '&deg;' + '<br>' + 'Swipe Direction: ' + swipeDirection  + '<br><br><span style="font-size:.5em;">(Please wait for green screen before swiping again)<\/span>';
} else {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "ELSE" + 'Start H:' + startX + ' V:' + startY + '<br>' +  ' End H:' + curX + ' V:' + curY  + '<br>' + "Swipe Length: " + swipeLength + '<br>' + 'Swipe Angle: ' + swipeAngle + '&deg;' + '<br>' + 'Swipe Direction: ' + swipeDirection  + '<br><br><span style="font-size:.5em;">(Please wait for green screen before swiping again)<\/span>';
     touchEnabledElement.style.backgroundimage = 'railroadtracks2.png';
```

Comment: There is no jQuery anywhere in this question

Answer (score 1):

Try `.backgroundImage` (NB: capital "i")

Comment: Tried that and still no effect.

Comment: did you try David's fix to the property too? "url(...)"

Comment: That gives me an error message "can't find variable url". This is my work-in-progress: tinyurl.com/62hakh2

Answer (score 1):

The property is `backgroundImage` not `backgroundimage`, and the syntax of a URL in CSS is `url(railroadtracks.png)` not just `railroadtracks.png`

Comment: That gives me an error message "can't find variable url". This is my work-in-progress:  http://tinyurl.com/62hakh2

Comment: You still need to quote the string. `"url(railroadtracks.png)"`

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning (=) instead of comparing (==) here:

```
if ( (swipeDirection = 'down') && (swipeLength >= 180) ) {
```

Comment: You're right. I changed that and the if statement works but the image still doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do `swipeDirection = 'down'` instead of `swipeDirection == 'down'`?

Comment: You're right. I changed that and the if statement works but the image still doesn't change.

Comment: Try `url('railroadtracks.png')`? And did you make sure your `touchEnabledElement` exists?

Comment: touchEnabledElement exists because I use it elsewhere on the page:  http://tinyurl.com/62hakh2